# Reformatting code with R# in a single keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting, resharper

Using the R# keyboard shortcut for formatting code presents the following window:

[image]

which forces me click the *Run* button every time.

Is there a way to bind a keyboard shortcut directly into the *Reformat Code* option, rather than just opening this dialog window?

**Edit:** To make things clear, I don't *actually* click the Run button with the cursor, I press Enter. (I still find it annoying, and wish for a direct shortcut.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Oh sweet.. I just checked Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and found the command "ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode". It seems to execute ReSharper's code formatting function without popping up the dialog. Give it a try but try to not break your fingers... the default is ctrl-alt-shift-f :D That needs a rebind...

Comment: With Resharper 9, I still got the dialog shown in the question when triggering this command. But there was a little checkbox at the bottom that said something like "Use this profile for silent code cleanup." I selected "Reformat Code," checked the box, clicked "Run," and after that, silent cleanup really was silent.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't answer the question directly I want to propose `Ctrl-K-D` as an alternative. This will invoke Visual Studio built-in formatting. It is less thorough but also less intrusive.

Comment: That is what I was using until now, but I find the R# formatting tool much more to my liking.